# SCSS Global variables

Tags: css, angular, sass

I am wanting to have a global asset path for a light mode and dark mode.

`$asset-path: "/assets/LightMode/PNGs" !default;`

when the body has the class `.dark`, this needs to change to:

`$asset-path: "/assets/DarkMode/PNGs";`

This `$asset-path` is being used by quite a few elements down the line, but there are a few problems with getting this working:

- I can't use CSS variables eg `var(--name)` because they don't get interpreted before the URL is read so it tries to access the URL `var(--name)/asset`
- I am using Angular as a framework and I need to use these variables in a local CSS file so I can't access the `body` element.
- Using `$asset-path: "/assets/DarkMode/PNGs" !global;` inside `body.dark` sets the theme regardless of whether the body actually has that class or not

So how do I set global SCSS variables if the body has a class of dark? Is there a better way of doing this that I have not thought of?